# In-solution references not working with .NET Standard 2.0

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-standard

I am currently porting a project from .NET Framework 4.6.2 to .NET Standard 2.0 but it appears that in-solution references (e.g. referencing a .NET Standard 2.0 library from a .NET Framework 4.6.2 Unit Tests project) is broken. Downgrading the library to .NET Standard 1.X fixes it but it is not a solution as .NET Standard 2.0 becomes unusable. I obtained similar results when referencing a .NET Standard 2.0 library from a .NET Core 2.0 project.
If we leave the solution and reference the same .NET Standard 2.0 project from an external project it works flawlessly, and to be sure I also tested referencing a .NET Framework library from a .NET Framework Unit Tests project and it works just as well.
If it can be useful, I am using the latest Visual Studio 15.3.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using ReSharper? I had a similar issue in VS2017, where the in-solution reference between a .Net Standard 2.0 Project and .Net Core 2.0 MSTest Project. The issue turned out to be ReSharper, once I disabled Resharper the in-solution references worked.

Comment: It was indeed ReSharper, disabling it fixed the issue, this issue should probably be reported to them.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same behavior two weeks ago. If you have ReSharper, I'm almost certain that you don't have the [latest version](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/download-thanks.html?code=RSU&platform=windows). My suggestion is, instead of disabling ReSharper, you go and update it. It worked pretty well for me.

In case you wanted to know what is new in this version, you can [click here](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/whatsnew/).